# Different stylesheet for different pages not working fully

Tags: theme-development, page-template, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to use different stylesheets for different pages, but it doesnt kinda work. For example i made a page called 'Contact' and assigned the template contact-template.php to it.

and this is how i enqueued my stylesheets:

```
if(!is_admin()){
    if(is_front_page()){
        wp_enqueue_style('front-page-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    }
    else if(is_page('contact-template.php')){
        wp_enqueue_style('page-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-contact.css');
    }
    else{
        wp_enqueue_style('default-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-default.css');
    }
}
```

i already tryed using is_page_template('contact-template.php'); but not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
is_page('contact-template.php')
```

Try:

```
is_page('contact')
```

`is_page` expects a post ID or slug.

If instead you want to enqueue this CSS for any page using this template, put the enqueueing PHP into the template itself.